# jQuery get css background-color value of parent element

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I want to do something a bit awkward and my pseudo code isn't working, but should explain what I'm trying to do. I have groups of 4 radio buttons, in 6 separate divs, so 24 radios in total. Each div is a particular background colour. When a radio button within a particular div is selected, I need to grab the colour of the div the selected radio button is within, and have it stored in a variable ready to apply it to an element that'll be created next...

```
    $("#voucher_selection_container input:radio").change(function(){
    //var color = $(this).parent("div").css("background-color");
    //alert(color);
    $("#voucher_customisation_container").slideDown(600);
    //$("#voucher_customisation_container .voucher_box").css("background-color", color);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. :) Thanks.

Comment: Is this about right?  http://jsfiddle.net/5ttMj/1/  If you change `parent` to `closest` it works: http://jsfiddle.net/5ttMj/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `closest()` to find the next matching element up the DOM tree

```
var color = $(this).closest("div").css("background-color");
```

Comment: Hi, you're right. Parent would give me a fieldset, I'd need parent().parent(), obviously that's not right, closest works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Note that you could have used .parents('div') aswell

Comment: @Toni `parents('div')` will get you all parents that are divs

Comment: I see, but there is a chance that .closest returns a child, isn't it? I would apply a class to the div to make sure. then parents('.class') shouldn't fail

Comment: No, closest find the closest UP the DOM tree only, not down.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#voucher_selection_container input:radio").change(function(){

     var color = $(this).parent("div").css("backgroundColor");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
 var backColor = $(this).parent().css("background-color");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the parent function you'll be able to access the parent div

```
$('radio').click(function(){
  $(this).parent();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#voucher_selection_container input:radio").change(function(){
    var color = $(this).parent().css("background-color");
    alert(color);
    //$("#voucher_customisation_container").slideDown(600);
    $("#voucher_customisation_container .voucher_box").css("background-color", color); 
});
```

Try this